# What is the cause of curved lines formed by the sediments?

Tags: everyday-life

I was making some hung curd and had tied some curd in a cloth to drain all its water. However I noticed that as the water dripped, a circle was formed with the dripping point as its centre and there was a pattern of curved paths along the circumference of the circle. The curved lines are thin but get thicker at the tips. Can someone please explain what is the cause of this pattern?[image]